# Existence of certain graph gadget related to coloring odd hole free graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Wondering about the existence of graph gadget related to coloring
(or 3-coloring) odd hole free graphs.

Let $G$ be simple $k$-chromatic connected graph with two
vertices $u,v$.

Is it possible $G$ to satisfy:

1. All **induced** $uv$ paths have odd order (even number of
   edges).
2. In all proper $k$ colorings, $u$ and $v$ have distinct colors
3. (optional) $G$ doesn't contain induced $C_{2n+1}$ for $n>1$

If this is possible, there is reduction $F$ to odd hole free $F'$.

Replace an edge $u'v'$ by the gadget $G$ where $u'=u,v'=v$ and the
rest vertices of $G$ are new vertices.

According to graphclasses coloring odd hole free is NP hard
and 3-coloring is unknown.

Computer search suggest small gadgets don't exist (modulo errors).

Comment: Note that your gadget cannot be perfect, since in perfect/Berge graphs, the vertices $u$ and $v$ you describe (they are called an "even pair" in the literature) are such that the graph obtained from $G$ by identifying $u$ and $v$, has the same chromatic number as $G$.

Comment: @Louis Thank you. I suppose it is more likely to have odd hole rather than odd anti-hole in case it exists?

Comment: @Lois This paper claims merging even pairs preserves the chromatic number of any graph:  http://www.ime.usp.br/~cris/gcomb/pronex/ps-dvi-files/celina/livro.ps.gz

Comment: Crossposted on cstheory, attempted answer there: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31982/existence-of-certain-graph-gadget-related-to-coloring-odd-hole-free-graph